# Display definition term and description inline

Tags: css

I am using a definition list for some elements on the page and need them to display inline, e.g.: they **normally** look like:

**<def term>** 
        <def desc> 
        <def desc>

and I need them to look like (note the multiple DD's):

**<def term>** <def desc> <def desc>
**<def term>** <def desc> <def desc>
**<def term>** <def desc> <def desc>

I can get them to work fine using floats in moz but no matter what I try they will not work in IE, I typically get something like:

**<def term>** <def desc> <def desc> <def desc> <def desc> <def desc> <def desc> 
**<def term>** 
**<def term>**

Has anyone found a solution to this problem, I would really like to avoid adding extra markup where possible, but short of changing them to an unordered list im out of ideas :(

Thanks in advance

Comment: To me your problem is unclear. You cant add markup with CSS. Looking at your first and second code quote this looks like this. Can you add real world HTML?

Comment: I don't think he wants to format his code, simply get the dt's and dd's to float correctly, so that every dd comes on the same line as the dt, and then a linebreak for the next dt.

Answer (score 9):

**Note:** you have to avoid spaces between the DD elements for this work work correctly.

No need for hacks for IE8+:

```
dd,
dt{
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
}
dd:before {
    content: ' '; /* space them */
}
dt:before { /* insert line break before <dt> */
    content:"\A";
    white-space:pre;
}
dt:first-child:before { /* disable line break before the first <dt> */
    content: none;
}
```

If you don't need to support IE8, skip the 4th CSS rule and just use this selector for the 3rd one: `dt:not(:first-child):before`

The result should be something like this:  [(demo)](http://codepen.io/bfred-it/pen/gjHDn)

```
DT DD DD
DT DD DD
```

If you want to be *real cool*, you can replace the 2nd rule with this:

```
dd + dd:before {
    content: ', '; /* add comma between definitions */
}

dt:after {
    content: ':';
}
```

The result should be something like this:  [(demo)](http://codepen.io/bfred-it/pen/KDHam)

```
DT: DD, DD
DT: DD, DD
```

Answer (score 2):

default stylesheet

> dt,dd { float: left;}
>   dd + dt { clear: left; }

ie 6 & 7 stylesheet:

> dt { float: none;} 
>   dd { 
>     position: relative;
>     top: -19px; /*depending on your line-height*/
>   }

ie6

> http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Thomas, Thanks for your response, sadly the DD's all still appear to wrap onto the same line in IE7, which suggest that the DT is not clearing properly. Did this solution work for you in IE7?

Comment: Matt, you're right, it breaks in ie7:

dd { float: left; position: relative; top: -19px; /*depending on your line-height*/}
dd + dt {clear: left;}

fixes it for ie7. not very pretty, would have to sit in ie specific stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing the float in the dt's? Like this:

```
dt { clear: left; }
dd { float: left; }
```

---

**Edit:** Here's a cross-browser solution that validates:

```
dd,dt{ display: inline; }

<dl>
 <dt>1</dt><dd>1.1</dd><dd>1.2<br/></dd>
 <dt>2</dt><dd>2.1</dd><dd>2.2<br/></dd>
</dl>
```

However, as you can see, that br is pretty nasty and non-semantic. Hopefully someone else can come up with a better solution. :)

Comment: Hi kaba, yes thats what I tried initially and it works fine in moz but sadly IE does not clear the float correctly :( so all of the DD's stack up

Answer (score 0):

just [give them all layout](http://haslayout.net/haslayout) , most simple way is to use CSS property
    .yourstuff {
        zoom: 1;
    }

Answer (score 0):

This works (admittedly only tested on FF 3.x.x and Opera 9.x, both on Ubuntu 8.04):

**CSS**:

```css
p {
    display: block;
}
dl {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
}
dt {
    display: block;
    width: 7em;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 0;
}
dd {
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    /* 'position: absolute' would probably work better, 
        and lose the line break left by the 'position: relative;' */
    top: -1em;
    left: 8em;
}
dt:hover + dd, dt:hover + dd + dd {
   /* Couldn't find a way to target all sibling 
      dds of a dt without the + operator (and listing all of them),
      but it works, albeit kludgy */
    display: inline;
}
dd:after {
    content:"; ";
}
dd:last-child:after {
    content:"";
}
```

**HTML**:

```html
<div id="content">
    <dl>
        <dt>first dt</dt><dd>first dt's first dd</dd><dd>first dt's second</dd>
        <dt>second dt</dt><dd>second dt's first dd</dd><dd>second dt's second</dd>
        <dt>third dt</dt><dd>third dt's third dd</dd><dd>third dt's second</dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

Link to working example, tested under FF 3 and Opera 9.x:
http://www.davidrhysthomas.co.uk/so/dls.html