# how to align textboxes side by side in a list view

Tags: css

I want to display fields in my list data side by side.  I am using dl,dt and dd for alignment, and I was able to display them one after the other; but, I need to display certain fields in a single row using these dl,dt and dd.

Could any one suggest how to do this alignment?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you improve on you question. I am not able to understand it. This could also help others to understand your question better

Comment: i want display fields in my list data side by side.I am using dl,dt and dd for alignment,and i was able to display them one after the other.
But i need to display certain fields in a single row using these dl,dt and dd 
Could any one suggest me how to do this alignment
Thanks!

Comment: could you post your current html and css code

Comment: <dl>
               
  <dt>A </dt>              
  <dd>${A}</dd>               
 <dt> S</dt>                
   <dd>${S}</dd>
   </dl>      I want to align A and S side by side in a single row

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857561/display-definition-term-and-description-inline

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work for you

```
 dd,dt{ display: inline; }
```